# Dynamic code with clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to create some dynamic code within clojure.  In the function below, the idea is that the conditions for the (and) macro will be dynamically generated.

```
(defn matching-keys [rec match-feed keys]
  (> (count (clojure.set/select #(and (for [k keys]
                                        (= (% k) (rec k))))
                                (set match-feed)))
     0))
```

So if it worked!! then this code would produce an (and) something like this when passed keys of `[:tag :attrs]`:

```
(and (= (% :tag) (rec :tag))
     (= (% :attrs) (rec :attrs)))
```

I've been messing around with various ``` `` and ```~` operators to try to make it work, and am now in a state of confusion.  Any guidance is welcome.

Thanks,

Colin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need dynamically generated code for this. Changing the anonymous function to `#(every? (fn [k] (= (% k) (rec k))) keys)` should do what you want without generating code at runtime.

The ability to use higher-order functions means that you should hardly ever need to dynamically generate code.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I kind of got there myself with: #(some true? (for [k keys] (= (% k) (rec k)))) but your solution is better. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use *eval* to evaluate a dynamically built form, e.g.:

```
(eval '(= 2 3))
```

Keep in mind that a dynamically evaluated form will have no access to the lexical context.  It means that:

```
(let [a 1 b 2]
  (eval '(+ a b)))
```

will not work.

However, it is still possible to use a dynamic environment:

```
(def a nil)
(def b nil)

(binding [a 1 b 2]
  (eval '(+ a b)))
```

Comment: +1 for the insights on dynamic vs. lexical binding with eval... I didn't know that!