# Clojure - Why load-string does not work in this case?

Tags: java, clojure

(load-string s) according to its document:

"Sequentially read and evaluate the set of forms contained in the string"

Why it does not work in the following code?

```
(let [fun #(+ 1 2)]
     (load-string "(fun)"))
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the lexical environment at all from load-string, so even this won't work:

```
(let [fun 12]
     (load-string "(+ 1 fun)"))
```

Only bound values work, see here:

[Dynamic code with clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934494/dynamic-code-with-clojure)